# Text classification with RapidMiner

Tags: classification, text-mining, k-nearest-neighbour, rapidminer

I have a folder for each class that contains some text files related to that class and need to implement a classifier for these files in RapidMiner with KNN algorithm.

Is there any sample?

Answer (score 4):

Check the samples in RapidMiner software first.

And the [videos](http://vancouverdata.blogspot.com/2010/11/text-analytics-with-rapidminer-loading.html) - Text Analytics with RapidMiner by Neil McGuigan is quite useful for text mining.